# ADSTS50011: The reply address does not match the reply addresses configured for the application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I have configured an application to use Skype for business Web SDK on azure portal. I have registered it successfully on AAD and done other necessary steps.

I am running it on my local machine on default IIS port i.e. 80 and name of web application is http://localhost/SkypeWebSDKSamples/ . While running the application its giving me error

> ADSTS50011: The reply address does not match the reply addresses
>   configured for the application".

The piece of code where its giving me error is below:

[image]

I have already put this URL in azure Reply URLs but its keep giving me same error. Below is screenshot:

[image]
 I have seen several links on stackoverflow and web and none of them is helping. I have spend already 6 hours on this thing. Any help or suggestions will be highly anticipated.

Comment: But you are setting up redirect URI to `location.href + 'websdk/token.html` and have `http://localhost/SkypeWebSDKSamples/` on AAD? Those do not match. You can see the `redirect_uri` parameter when the app redirects you to sign in. That one must exactly match one of the configured URIs in AAD.

Comment: @juunas: Thanks for your help, this code comes with skype for business SDK . So you mean to take the location.href + 'websdk/token.html URL which I am getting in code and put on AAD. Please suggests.

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I am saying.

Comment: I changed URL to http://localhost/SkypeWebSDKSamples/index.html in AAD and hard coded same on SDK code but still getting the same error.

Comment: I have even tried with https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk and its giving me same error.

Comment: If  you host your application on `http://localhost` and provide `http://localhost/*` as a reply url. You can see the detials here :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/developwebsdkappsforsfbonline#registering-your-application-in-azure-ad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the reply URL on azure to `http://localhost/*` and it works for me.

There is a NOTE in [**the official documeantation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/developwebsdkappsforsfbonline#registering-your-application-in-azure-ad):

> Note: During development it is a common practice to host your
>   application on `http://localhost` and provide `http://localhost/*` as
>   a reply url.