# AAD Authentication inside AzureKubernetesService

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, azure-aks

I developed an application that uses Azure AD Authentication for a single tenant.

I would like to host it inside AKS, but it seems not to be possible, as described below:

The problem is that the application must be running as https if it is not in localhost, but my pod is running on http protocol (as usual). Even if my aks cluster service is running as Https, the callback uri seems like to be looking for the protocol on the pod where it's running, so it redirects the request to http://mydomain and not https://mydomain, returning the "Correlation Error" or "app id doesnt exists" (because the mapped uri was https://)

The redirect URI can not be mapped to http on Azure App as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url).

I've made it work using a certificate inside my pod on the application build using Kestrel Certificate. But it seems not to be a good solution.

Does anyone knows a more suitable workaround?

Comment: Have you got chance to try like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50442442/adsts50011-the-reply-address-does-not-match-the-reply-addresses-configured-for?rq=1) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58078379/aadsts500112-the-reply-address-http-testurl-does-not-match-the-reply-addres?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now there is no other solution available as we have restrictions in redirect URL as per the document you are following.